# generic failure for SASL LOGIN

Tags: postfix, smtp, sasl, courier

few years ago I've set up my server using this guide: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ at that time machine was running ubuntu 8.04 LTS, recently I've updated machine to 12.04 LTS but can't force SASL to work, so atm sending mail is only possible using web SquirellMail

I can provide requred configuration, but for know this is what I have in logs:

```
Apr 19 10:59:10 web_addr postfix/smtpd[7669]: connect from __some_IP__
Apr 19 10:59:22 web_addr postfix/smtpd[7669]: Anonymous TLS connection established from __some_IP__: TLSv1 with cipher RC4-MD5 (128/128 bits)
Apr 19 10:59:27 web_addr postfix/smtpd[7669]: warning: __some_IP__: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: generic failure
```

and don't have any more information about reason of failure - where to even search for cause of problems? Receving and sending data used to work fine, now I got these.

also:

```
testsaslauthd -u _valid_user_ -p _user_password_ -f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux
```

results in:

```
0: NO "authentication failed"
```

postconf -a

```
cyrus
dovecot
```

saslauthd -v

```
saslauthd 2.1.25
authentication mechanisms: sasldb getpwent kerberos5 pam rimap shadow ldap
```

Comment: Welcome to [SF]. We are not a forum, please do not add meta-words like "Fixed" to your post. If you found the answer it should be posted as an Answer, and accepted when you have the chance. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on how the [SE] sites are Q&A sites and different from a forum. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The OP wanted to add:

after few more tries, tests and a lot of debug...

found that I had typo in configuration file:

```
/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf
```

found it when I typed: saslfinger -s

and there were these lines:

```
-- content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login cram-md5 digest-md5
#mech_list: plain login pam
log_level: 15
allow_plaintext: true
#auxprop_plugin: mysql
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: --- replaced ---
sql_passw: _MY_PASSWORD_
```

have not noticed typo at first but noticed that one line had '--- replaced ---' information and second didn't but should...